# Error checking 'if' conditions - Windows .bat

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am having trouble with multiple if statements.

The renaming of the file depends on the string in the 3rd column (tokens=3).  I have no problem grabbing the 3rd column string and setting it to a variable %fy%, and no problems setting the sixteen, seventeen, and eightteen variables.  The error is occurring with multiple IF statements.  Note - If I just run the code with 1 IF statement it works correctly.  Why are multiple ifs tripping this up?

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=3 delims=, skip=1" %%i in (DownloadedData.csv) do if not defined line set "fy=%%i"
    echo %fy%

SET sixteen=^"FY16^
SET seventeen=^"FY17^        
SET eightteen=^"FY18^

IF %fy% == %sixteen% goto :YEAR16
IF %fy% == %seventeen% goto :YEAR17
IF %fy% == %eightteen% goto :YEAR18

:YEAR16
set "filename=DATA_2016.csv" 
echo %filename%
goto :COMMONEXIT
:YEAR17
set "filename=DATA_2017.csv" 
echo %filename%
goto :COMMONEXIT
:YEAR18
set "filename=DATA_2018.csv" 
echo %filename%
goto :COMMONEXIT

:COMMONEXIT
pause

REM - Code then goes on to use the filename variable to rename the file in the download folder.
```

Comment: When you say "tripping this up", what do you mean? What is the consequence of the multiple if statements that is undesired?

Comment: "The syntax of the command is incorrect"

Comment: Yeah, I get that too whilst running a test. The problem lies in your line `SET sixteen=^"FY16^`. That doesn't look correct to me. The ^ is a bitwise OR operation, so I don't know what that's doing with a string. And when I run that set command from the command line, it prompts me for input to add to the variable.

Comment: That single " is apart of the string.  That is why I used ^'s.  Can you suggest how to set a variable to "year in a more effective manner?

Comment: Just drop the ^ characters then. You don't need them. `set sixteen="FY16` is all you need.

Comment: Also, if you wish to go to a label, just write `goto COMMONEXIT`. You don't need the preceding colon, except when defining the label.

Comment: @ManoDestra ^ is an escape character in batch. It is *not* xor in batch.

Comment: In some instances, yes. However, not required here for ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe ManoDestra has a working solution.

I think your FOR /F statement is wrong. I believe you wanted

```
set "fy="
for /f .... do if not defined fy set "fy=%%i"
```

If that is the case, you could dramatically simplify your code to:

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=3 delims=, skip=1" %%i in (DownloadedData.csv) do goto %%i

:"FY16
set "filename=DATA_2016.csv"
echo %filename%
goto :COMMONEXIT
:"FY17
set "filename=DATA_2017.csv"
echo %filename%
goto :COMMONEXIT
:"FY18
set "filename=DATA_2018.csv"
echo %filename%
goto :COMMONEXIT

:COMMONEXIT
pause

REM - Code then goes on to use the filename variable to rename the file in the download folder
```

Or better yet:

```
@echo off

set "fy="
for /f "tokens=3 delims=, skip=1" %%i in (DownloadedData.csv) do if not defined fy set "fy=%%i"
set "filename=DATA_20%fy:~-2%.csv"
echo %filename%
pause
REM - Code then goes on to use the filename variable to rename the file in the download folder
```

Comment: Hi @dbenham, When using the first part of code followed by "you could dramatically simplify your code to:".....no matter what is in the 3rd column, whether its FY15,FY16,FY17...its still only catching the FY16 section and setting filename to "filename=DATA_2016.csv".  I cannot use the second bit you posted because the filename is much more complex than shown.

Comment: Turns out there was no error.  When running this file multiple times it was storing fy indefinitely.  I added startlocal and endlocal around the renaming section and it worked.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=3 delims=, skip=1" %%i in (DownloadedData.csv) do if not defined line set "fy=%%i"
echo %fy%

SET sixteen="FY16
SET seventeen="FY17
SET eighteen="FY18

IF "%fy%"" == "%sixteen%"" goto YEAR16
IF "%fy%"" == "%seventeen%"" goto YEAR17
IF "%fy%"" == "%eighteen%"" goto YEAR18
GOTO COMMONEXIT :: Here, if you wish to exit as a default if none matched. Otherwise, it will fall into YEAR16.

:YEAR16
set filename=DATA_2016.csv
goto COMMONEXIT

:YEAR17
set filename=DATA_2017.csv
goto COMMONEXIT

:YEAR18
set filename=DATA_2018.csv
goto COMMONEXIT

:COMMONEXIT
echo %filename%
pause

REM - Code then goes on to use the filename variable to rename the file in the download folder.

set fy=
set sixteen=
set seventeen=
set eighteen=
```

Upon setting the initial character to be a double quote, you then need to match that double quote at the end of your comparison, hence why I have a single double quote at the start and two at the end.

Comment: +1, But the quotes do not have to be paired if they are escaped. You could have done this: `IF ^%fy% == ^%sixteen% goto YEAR16`. Or you could have used one quote at the end: `IF %fy%" == %sixteen%" goto YEAR16`. Visually, it looks unbalanced, but so does your code with 3 quotes.

Comment: I'd use delayed expansion for such string comparisons as they will fail if one of the values has got balanced quotation; or I'd remove all quotes prior to comparison: `set "fy=%fy:"=%"`...